# How to sign an XML with a Digital Signature?

Tags: html, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

I need to sign the following XML code, but I do not know how to calculate "DigestValue" or "SignatureValue". Can this be done with Java or JavaScript?

Can someone please help me?

```html
<Body wsu:Id="id-1">
  <ns5:upload xmlns:ns4="http://msa.ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:ns3="http://idp.ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:ns2="http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:ns5="http://edt.health.ontario.ca/">
    <upload>
      <content> AAAA</content>
      <description>Demo</description>
      <resourceType>CL</resourceType>
    </upload>
  </ns5:upload>
</Body>

<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-6">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
      <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="SOAP-ENV               ebs soap-sec soapenv sp tns wsdl wsp wsse wsu xs xsi" />
    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
    <ds:Reference URI="#id-1">
      <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
          <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="SOAP-ENV ebs soap-sec soapenv sp tns wsdl wsp wsse wsu xs xsi" />
        </ds:Transform>
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
      <ds:DigestValue>FkhA37COGmsKeEH50LAGhKntvRpD0+xOGsGzXAV210k=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignatureValue> HmOiZS4gZbxv07+sLjyi7Vfg3Rfpvr3IVnaHfRp4aKvg5yBFlLocPIYwhUhmCCs1LXrJxR0hsbe0K2sz3ML5hH+PDEGetlPKSN9R1x9 K95w7V 1JQcTUULiVgNGLCfxgFV2HNy1iNvlTc7COS+7w4xSgsY4KlVgrBw0T1srhHpUA=
  </ds:SignatureValue>
  <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-0EE1C2718CEDCA9FC213407274954662">
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-0EE1C2718CEDCA9FC213407274954663">
      <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-0EE1C2718CEDCA9FC213407274954261" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-                open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
```

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. You need to do it the correct way for your particular API. Consult its documentation; we can't answer this for you.

Comment: Have a look at the [xml-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml-signature/info) tag. It should answer most of your questions.

Comment: You asked, "Can this be done with Java or Javascript?" You want to do this on client (browser) side or server side? Where is the (Private Key of) Digital Signature ?